# AngularJS HTML template lags behind scope updates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an issue wherein I have an array of object that I render using `ng-repeat`. Not all of them are displayed at once though, but instead I have implemented a simple mechanism to determine which one is rendered. Consider the following controller:

```
$scope.items = [ ...{}]; // array of items

let current_selected_index = 0;

$scope.selectItem = (i) => current_selected_index = i;

$scope.isItemSelected = (i) => current_selected_index === i;

$scope.isFirstItem = () => current_selected_index === 0;
$scope.isLastItem = () => current_selected_index === $scope.items.length - 1;
```

And the following template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-show="isItemSelected($index)">
    {{ item.prop }}
    <div class="button__Wrapper">
        <button type="button" ng-show="!isFirstItem()" ng-click="selectItem($index - 1)">Go Back</button>
        <button type="button" ng-show="!isLastItem()" ng-click="selectItem($index + 1)">Go Forward</button>
        <button type="button" ng-show="isLastItem()" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is as follows. Let's say you're looking at the first item. All the buttons are rendered as they should be, i.e. there's no "Back" button.

You click on "Go forwards" and the second item appears, together with the "Go back" button.

Now, my issue is that if you now click "Go back", the first item is displayed, but the "Go back" button lingers for a second or two before disappearing.

The same goes for going from the penultimate to the last item. Both "Go forwards" and "Submit" are displayed alongside one another briefly before "Go forwards" disapperas. It also affects going back from the last item.

I have manually checked that all of the required flags are updated immediately and they are. The whole app is also *relatively* light on watchers, coming in at around 110 of them.

I have tried using `ng-cloak` but to my knowledge, the problem doesn't lie in partially rendered templates so it didn't work. I've also tried a version with `ng-switch`, but that yielded the same results.

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.4.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: typo `current_selected_index = 0`? should be `===`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yeah sorry, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: can't [replicate it with your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/mP5Y2cVFbcDry8fgJc2i?p=preview). Is there any other logic involved? _What about CSS (`button__Wrapper`)?_

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thank you very much! I hadn't thought about that, turns out a designer on our team left in a `transition` css prop on the buttons that caused this.